# Retrieve value from listview row

Tags: android, listview, android-lazyadapter

I'm using LazyAdaptor to create a listview with some data I'm parsing from a web server. Each row has a ImageView that is acting like a button and what I'm trying to do when the ImageView is clicked it will retrieve a value in the row named "reference". I'm trying to just Toast it as a quick way to make sure I'm grabbing the correct reference ID. I added a OnClick method and was able to retrieve the "position" but not sure how to grab the reference ID. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    RowHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);

    holder = new RowHolder();
    holder.reference = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.reference);
    holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.vicinity = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.vicinity);
    holder.checkin = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.check_in);
    vi.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (RowHolder) vi.getTag();
}
    HashMap<String, String> placeList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    placeList = data.get(position);

    holder.reference.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFERENCE));
    holder.name.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
    holder.vicinity.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_VICINITY));


    holder.checkin.setTag(position);
    holder.checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: u need to set the click listener when convertView is null

Comment: you can seTag the values and use getTag. do the same thing u did for position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys. I actually was able to do the following to return all the values in a alertdialog.

```
 final HashMap<String, String> finalPlaceList = placeList;
    holder.checkin.setTag(finalPlaceList);
    holder.checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(activity, "Row Details", v.getTag().toString() ,false);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
  holder.checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFERENCE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and

```
final HashMap<String, String> placeList = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

put final keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Instead get string from your View using tab you should use  this...

```
holder.checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, holder.reference.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using onItemClick listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

// your code here. . . 
  }

            });
```